# Cannot partition 3TB drive with GParted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 64-bit, gparted

I have a 3TB drive which I hope to partition as ext4. GParted is being partially helpful. The device is connected via an eSATA cable into a disk caddy.

This is the gparted_details.html

What's curious is that the invocation line reads `mkfs.ext4 -F -O ^64bit -L '' '/dev/sda1'` but the error message in the htm reads `64-bit filesystem support is not enabled. The larger fields afforded by this feature enable full-strength checksumming. Pass -O 64bit to rectify.` or is that caret before the '64' significant?

After I saved the htm file, a number of dialog boxes appeared regarding sync errors.

```
GParted 0.30.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Create Primary Partition #1 (ext4, 2.73 TiB) on /dev/sda  00:00:56    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 5860532223
size: 5860530176 (2.73 TiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sda1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 274877906944  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 3000590925824  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 3000591384576  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 3000591441920  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sda  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sda1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: ext4
create new ext4 file system  00:00:55    ( ERROR )

mkfs.ext4 -F -O ^64bit -L '' '/dev/sda1'  00:00:55    ( ERROR )

64-bit filesystem support is not enabled. The larger fields afforded by this feature enable full-strength checksumming. Pass -O 64bit to rectify.
Creating filesystem with 732566272 4k blocks and 183148544 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 326821ce-0b99-4928-b0cc-8efeb99a3cf4
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)

Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.

========================================
```

**ABOUT AN HOUR LATER**

It occurred to me that I could run `badblocks` and just see if there were any, this not being a new drive.

```
sudo badblocks -w -s -v /dev/sda -o badblocks.txt
```

So that's a read/write test with status messages outputting the bad block numbers to badblocks.txt. After a few minutes badblocks.txt filled up with 1.2GB of dodgy block numbers.

`Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.` is the key: the block where the superblock was to be written was bad.

**QUITE A FEW HOURS LATER**

So the issue was badblocks. I repartitioned, giving a generous slab of space to the bad sectors area, and then created my slightly smaller /dev/sda1. I'm currently running badblocks over the new partition just in case.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `badblocks` to do this. "*It  is  strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs*". See my answer. I'd start over. If this is a new, under-warranty drive, I'd return it.

Comment: Well it most certainly is NOT a new under-warranty disk. I have started over. I don't expect to have much usable disk at the end of the process but am going to try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is a new, fresh, empty, 3TB HDD, you first need to use `gparted` to lay down a fresh **GPT Partition Table** (this WILL wipe the disk), then create the desired size ext4 partition(s).

**Update #1:**

**Bad Blocking**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Which is what I have done. However, I think I have found the issue: bad blocks (see above).

Comment: @bugmagnet Are you booted to a 64-bit OS? Is your BIOS in UEFI mode? Where/how are you seeing bad blocks? Then please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @bugmagnet Does your external eSATA drive enclosure have its own AC power supply?

Comment: Yes, the enclosure has its own A/C power

Comment: @bugmagnet You didn't answer my previous comment's questions.

Comment: Marking this as the closest to the mark. After an all-night badblocks scan I'm thinking that this drive would be best handed over to an eWaste company as the number of bads filled a 1.2GB text file

Comment: @bugmagnet did you do the bad blocking using your `badblocks` command, or do as I suggested and used my instructions?

Comment: I did use badblocks first. However, I will be using your approach later today. Should this situation ever reoccur, I will use your method first.

Comment: @bugmagnet Status please... is your drive workable after using my procedure?

Comment: Totally broken. Was a broken drive to start with that I had previously used testdisk to extract about 300GB of data from. Off to the eWaste with it.